# Big O- and Omega-Notation for functions

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation

I want to find out how to check, if the following relationships are true or false.

f(n) = nlog(n!); g(n) = nlog(2n^3n); Check, if f(n) = O(g(n)) and/or f(n) = Ω(g(n)) true/false;

f(n) = 3n^2; g(n) = 9^(base3-logn); Check, if f(n) = O(g(n)) and/or f(n) = Ω(g(n)) true/false;

I am very new to this topic, so i would be very grateful, if someone could explain it to me. If something is not understandable, don't hesitate and ask me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, but I am absolutely unsure about the result. Second example: I simplified g(n) and got n^2. From this I conclude that g(n) is an upper bound for f(n) and O(g(n)) is valid. Since, to my knowledge, prefactors are negligible in the dominant term, I would say at this point that g(n) is also a lower bound for f(n). But it is exactly at this point that I have the big uncertainty.

Comment: in the first example is it (2n)^(3n) or 2n^3n ?

Comment: It is nlog(2n)^(3n)

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/824/755

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In second example if you have $f(n)=3n^2$ and $g(n)=n^2$, then, of course $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$.

For first enough to note, that $n! < (2n)^{3n}$.

Comment: I understand that (2n)^3n is the dominant term. Is that why we just need to concentrate on (2n)^3n and n!? If that is the case, then only O(g(n)) is true, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Written inequality implies $n \log n! < n \log (2n)^{3n}$ for logarithm with base $>1$.